# postgres update table based on another table

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am relatively new to postgres (I am a django user - use pgsql via the orm), and I am trying to figure out a way to insert content into a specfic column - but so far, am not having any luck. So, I first have a database `dzmodel_uf` with two columns: `id` (which is the PK) and `content` - both of which are populated (say 50 entries).

Now, I would like to create another table, which references (foreign keys) to `id` of `dzmodel_uf`. So, I do the following:

```
--INITIALIZATION
CREATE TABLE MyNewTable(id integer REFERENCES dzmodel_uf (id));
ALTER TABLE ONLY FullTextSearch ADD CONSTRAINT mynewtable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

which works fine. Now, I create a column on my MyNewTable table like so:

```
ALTER TABLE MyNewTable ADD COLUMN content_tsv_gin tsvector;
```

..which also works fine. Finally, I would like to add the content from `dzmodel_uf` - column `content` like so:

```
UPDATE MyNewTable SET content_tsv_gin = to_tsvector('public.wtf', dzmodel_uf(content) )
```

.. but this FAILS and says that column `content` does not exist..

In a nutshell, I am not sure how I can reference values from another table.

Comment: If the new table is still empty you should INSERT, not UPDATE.

Comment: @joop: I tried this. When I do this - PGsql does not seem to print out any error messages - but I can see that the table is empty (MyNewTable) wheras `dzmodel_uf(content)` has around 50 entries!

Comment: What is your question about. The `UPDATE` statement or the table design? It's best to ask *one* clearly defined question. But first you need to learn the basics yourself.

Comment: @JohnJ If you update an empty table, the update can only affect zero rows. Elementary, dear Watson...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood the question (it is rather fuzzy).There are no rows in the target table, so you have to add them.
You need `INSERT`, not `UPDATE` :

```
INSERT INTO  MyNewTable (id,content_tsv_gin)
SELECT dzu.id, to_tsvector( public.wtf, dzu.content )
FROM dzmodel_uf dzu
  ;
```

Comment: I should have known better - I needed an INSERT and not an UPDATE - Quite stupid of me - Sorry, I am not a real programmer - just trying!